# Is there any way to get Play framework and JPA to use underscores in column names?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I'm trying to build a Play! app running against an existing database where all the columns have underscores to separate words. This means I have to put an `@Column` annotation on each field to specify a different name. Is there anyway to get Play! to use underscores by default?

Comment: It should insert underscores based on what?

Comment: words are separated by underscores instead of camel case

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If Play uses Hibernate, as the other answers suggest, you will have to [implement a custom `NamingStrategy`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#configuration-namingstrategy).

Here's a sample NamingStrategy that converts all column names from lower camel to lower case with underscores, using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com):

```
public class CustomNamingStrategy extends ImprovedNamingStrategy {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -306957679456120781L;

    @Override
    public String columnName(final String columnName) {
        return CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL
                         .to(CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE, columnName);
    }
}
```

Configure it like this:

> add the following line to
>   application.conf to configure the
>   NamingStrategy
>
> `hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=<your naming strategy classname>`

**Reference:**

- [Implementing a custom
  `NamingStrategy` (Hibernate Reference)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#configuration-namingstrategy)
- [`NamingStrategy` (Hibernate JavaDocs)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/index.html?org/hibernate/cfg/NamingStrategy.html)
- [How to set up a different Naming
  Strategy (Play-Framework Google Group)](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/bee380c98b173199)
- [`CaseFormat` (Guava JavaDoc)](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/base/CaseFormat.html)

Comment: AFAIK ImprovedNamingStrategy does just that. Converts to lowercase+underscore. So, you just have to set it to ImprovedNamingStrategy. +1 for a good answer anyway ;)

Comment: @Bogdan a) thanks! b) true, didn't check that. But quite frankly: the Guava way looks more effective than the Hibernate way, so this may actually be an improvement nevertheless :-)

Answer (score 1):

The solution given works great, but as stated in the comments, [ImprovedNamingStrategy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/cfg/ImprovedNamingStrategy.html) does that, so there's no need to use Guava.

> An improved naming strategy that prefers embedded underscores to mixed
>   case names

You can simply add `hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy` in your `application.conf` (Tested in Play! Framework 1.2.5)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I read the doc correctly, the play framework is using Hibernate as the JPA implementation. AFAIK, there's no way to change the standard naming of Hibernate, so you'd have to add the annotations or provide the column names in the mapping XML file.

Comment: It sounds like @SeanPatrickFloyd answer is working (according to the OP and other questions I saw in SO). Would you mind editing/deleting your answer? better than getting downvotes and clearer to other readers!